# Web Scraping in R: Issues with parsing an HTML table

Tags: r, rvest

I have been trying to scrape a table from a website so that I can reformat it in R. I have done this before for other websites, but am finding this to be particularly challenging. My code is below:

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.barttorvik.com/schedule.php"
uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
page <- read_html(GET(URL, user_agent(uastring)))

tbls <- page %>%
  html_nodes("#tblData") %>% # name of the table on the website
  html_table(trim = FALSE) # This returns a data frame with the right columns but no data
```

If you run this, you will see that this returns an empty data frame (or a list of an empty data frame). I have been looking through other threads and have yet to find a fix.

I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table seems to have an addition row using `colspan="6"`

```
page %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>% tail(1)

{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <td colspan="6" style="background: #5b9bd5; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase;\r\ntext-align:center; font-size:10px">MOV Mean absolute error: 7.57 | Totals MAE: 29.8 | \r\nScore bias: -29.8 |<span cl ...
```

I think this could somehow be solved with the `unpivotr` package

Otherwise you can try:

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.barttorvik.com/schedule.php"
uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
page <- read_html(GET(URL, user_agent(uastring)))

cols<- page %>%
  html_nodes("th") %>%
  html_text()

data <- page %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  html_text()


finaldata <- data.frame(matrix(data[-126], ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)) # leavs out the colspan
names(finaldata) <- cols

finaldata

  Time (CT)                                              Matchup                            T-Rank Line TTQ      Result
1    6:00 PM                 45 North Carolina St. at 52 Virginia             Virginia -2.5, 58-55 (62%)  65            
2    6:00 PM                         55 Texas at 10 West Virginia        West Virginia -9.4, 67-58 (85%)  60            
3    8:00 PM                              58 Oklahoma at 5 Baylor              Baylor -12.8, 75-63 (89%)  59            
4    3:00 PM                    108 Charlotte at 186 Old Dominion            Charlotte -0.5, 57-56 (53%)  59            
5    6:00 PM                          146 Winthrop at 161 Radford              Radford -3.1, 74-71 (62%)  54            
6    7:30 PM              233 Texas Southern at 289 Grambling St.        Grambling St. -0.0, 76-75 (50%)  54            
7    3:00 PM                       241 LIU Brooklyn at 313 Wagner         LIU Brooklyn -0.9, 78-77 (53%)  49            
8    4:00 PM                215 Sacred Heart at 228 Robert Morris        Robert Morris -2.9, 74-71 (61%)  47            
9    6:30 PM             285 North Carolina A&T at 311 Morgan St.           Morgan St. -2.4, 72-69 (60%)  41            
10   6:00 PM                    259 UNC Asheville at 334 Longwood        UNC Asheville -2.8, 75-72 (61%)  40            
11   7:30 PM              179 Prairie View A&M at 322 Jackson St.     Prairie View A&M -5.5, 70-64 (72%)  39            
12   3:00 PM        301 North Carolina Central at 288 Florida A&M          Florida A&M -3.7, 65-61 (66%)  35            
13   6:00 PM                     234 Campbell at 331 Presbyterian             Campbell -3.1, 65-62 (64%)  34            
14   6:00 PM                          263 Bucknell at 156 Colgate             Colgate -10.6, 77-66 (85%)  34            
15   7:00 PM                           251 Rice at 60 North Texas         North Texas -16.2, 77-60 (94%)  32            
16   3:00 PM                  271 Merrimack at 188 St. Francis PA       St. Francis PA -8.2, 68-60 (82%)  30            
17   7:30 PM            315 Alcorn St. at 347 Arkansas Pine Bluff           Alcorn St. -3.2, 66-62 (64%)  28            
18   6:00 PM           317 St. Francis NY at 275 Mount St. Mary's     Mount St. Mary's -5.4, 67-61 (73%)  28            
19   9:05 PM                    310 Weber St. at 184 Portland St.        Portland St. -12.2, 78-66 (87%)  26            
20   6:00 PM                      327 Hampton at 248 Gardner Webb        Gardner Webb -10.2, 81-71 (82%)  24            
21  11:00 AM                                64 Yale at 348 Howard                Yale -21.6, 78-56 (98%)  19 Yale, 89-75
22   4:00 PM           278 Southern at 351 Mississippi Valley St.            Southern -10.5, 80-69 (84%)  15            
23   5:00 PM                    344 High Point at 306 USC Upstate         USC Upstate -10.0, 74-64 (84%)  15            
24   2:30 PM   350 Central Connecticut at 320 Fairleigh Dickinson Fairleigh Dickinson -14.6, 80-66 (91%)   5            
25   6:30 PM 352 Maryland Eastern Shore at 323 South Carolina St.  South Carolina St. -15.8, 75-60 (94%)   0
```

Comment: Maybe I do not understand something here. When I examine the page source I do not find `colspan` at all and I still find the problem of missing `tr` elements. It would be interesting to know where I made that mistake.

Comment: @r0berts did you try `page %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>% tail(1)`? what is the result you get?

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason your page (`http://www.barttorvik.com/schedule.php`) lacks opening `<tr>` elements for the table body. They are present in table header - `<thead>` part but not in `<tbody>`. You can easily verify this by opening page source (Ctrl+U) and searching for `tr>` - you will find closing elements `</tr>` in the table, but not `<tr>`.

If you correct this by adding missing elements all works. Browsers are programmed to cope with bad html (they render), but `rvest` does not know what to do with this, therefore it only displays header row. You could write code to insert `<tr>` before every `<td style='text-align:left;white-space:nowrap' id="mobileout">` or maybe you could tell page authors to correct their code generator?

```
> mypage <- read_html("~/tmp/test.html")
# test.html is file where I made the necessary replacements
> mypage%>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_table()
[[1]]
   Time (CT)                                              Matchup                            T-Rank Line TTQ Result
1    6:00 PM                 45 North Carolina St. at 51 Virginia             Virginia -2.5, 58-55 (62%)  65     NA
2    6:00 PM                         55 Texas at 10 West Virginia        West Virginia -9.4, 67-58 (85%)  60     NA
3    3:00 PM                    109 Charlotte at 186 Old Dominion            Charlotte -0.5, 57-56 (53%)  59     NA
4    6:00 PM                          145 Winthrop at 161 Radford              Radford -3.0, 74-71 (62%)  54     NA
5    7:30 PM              233 Texas Southern at 288 Grambling St.        Grambling St. -0.0, 76-75 (50%)  54     NA
6    3:00 PM                       240 LIU Brooklyn at 312 Wagner         LIU Brooklyn -0.9, 78-77 (54%)  49     NA
7    4:00 PM                215 Sacred Heart at 230 Robert Morris        Robert Morris -2.9, 74-71 (61%)  47     NA
8    6:30 PM             284 North Carolina A&T at 313 Morgan St.           Morgan St. -2.3, 72-69 (59%)  41     NA
9    6:00 PM                    259 UNC Asheville at 334 Longwood        UNC Asheville -2.8, 75-72 (61%)  40     NA
10   7:30 PM              179 Prairie View A&M at 323 Jackson St.     Prairie View A&M -5.5, 70-64 (72%)  39     NA
11   3:00 PM        302 North Carolina Central at 289 Florida A&M          Florida A&M -3.7, 65-61 (66%)  35     NA
12   6:00 PM                     234 Campbell at 331 Presbyterian             Campbell -3.1, 65-62 (64%)  34     NA
13   6:00 PM                          263 Bucknell at 156 Colgate             Colgate -10.5, 77-66 (84%)  34     NA
14   7:00 PM                           251 Rice at 61 North Texas         North Texas -16.2, 77-60 (94%)  32     NA
15   3:00 PM                  271 Merrimack at 188 St. Francis PA       St. Francis PA -8.2, 68-60 (82%)  30     NA
16   7:30 PM            315 Alcorn St. at 347 Arkansas Pine Bluff           Alcorn St. -3.2, 66-62 (64%)  28     NA
17   6:00 PM           317 St. Francis NY at 278 Mount St. Mary's     Mount St. Mary's -5.4, 67-61 (72%)  28     NA
18   9:05 PM                    310 Weber St. at 184 Portland St.        Portland St. -12.1, 78-66 (87%)  26     NA
19   6:00 PM                      327 Hampton at 249 Gardner Webb        Gardner Webb -10.3, 82-71 (82%)  24     NA
20  11:00 AM                                60 Yale at 348 Howard                Yale -21.6, 78-56 (98%)  18     NA
21   4:00 PM           277 Southern at 351 Mississippi Valley St.            Southern -10.5, 80-69 (83%)  15     NA
22   5:00 PM                    344 High Point at 306 USC Upstate         USC Upstate -10.0, 74-64 (84%)  15     NA
23   2:30 PM   350 Central Connecticut at 320 Fairleigh Dickinson Fairleigh Dickinson -14.6, 80-66 (91%)   5     NA
24   6:30 PM 352 Maryland Eastern Shore at 324 South Carolina St.  South Carolina St. -15.8, 76-60 (94%)   0     NA
```